# "Less" vs. "fewer"

Tags: word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I've just received a memo which says (effectively)

> As more people leave, there will be less people available.

I want that word to be *fewer.* Are there guidelines for which word ought to be used when?

Comment: People seem to be interpreting this question as about when it is correct to use less and fewer. It seems to me that the question is not about correct usage, but about guidelines for good usage (which is a proper subset of correct usage, in my opinion). Here I think hardcore descriptivism is compatible with saying "maybe reserving 'less' for mass nouns is reasonable style advice" [as it seems like Robert Baker is doing in nohat's answer]

Comment: I agree with nohat's answer, but my personal preference would align with yours: I like *fewer* in that sentence.

Comment: If that's really what the memo effectively said, then it was a crafty *don't look over here* ploy to provoke a less v. fewer debate and avoid examination of the delightfully circular argument it makes;-)

Comment: My girlfriend said we would have less arguments if I wasn't so pedantic. I said,"FEWER ARGUMENTS".

Comment: I couldn't care fewer

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I *could* care *less*.

Comment: @Oliphaunt: I could care even *lesser*.

Comment: So many people do not distinguish between the two words which have the same meaning that I believe we should regard both as acceptable. However I use fewer and not less when it concerns countable objects or people because that is, in my opinion, more elegant and better style.

Comment: _**Fewer/less** than a dozen (people)_?

Comment: Garner's fourth edition reads "As a noun, _less_ means “a smaller amount” or “something not as important.” Occasionally, writers make it an adjective when it should be a noun (_“He wants business to make money and everyone to pay less taxes_ [read _less **in** taxes_]). _Less_ for singular nouns or units of measure: _less tonic water, one less golfer, less than six ounces of epoxy_

Answer (score 100):

Ah, *less* vs. *fewer*. Another arrow in the prescriptivist’s quiver of pointless pedantry.

There's even a [Wikipedia article about the dispute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fewer_vs._less). There is also a [Language Log entry](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/003775.html) about the matter too.

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PA592&pg=PA593#v=onepage&q&f=false), a usage guide that looks carefully at the history of usage advice, the rule creating a clear separation for *less* and *fewer* was invented in 1770 by Rober Baker in his book *Reflections on the English Language*, where he wrote in [a comment on *less*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9iYusfpmmR0C&dq=Reflections%20on%20the%20English%20Language%20Robert%20Baker&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The Word is most commonly used in speaking of a Number; where I should think *Fewer* would do better. *No Fewer than a Hundred* appears to me not only more elegant than *No less than a Hundred*, but more strictly proper.

The Merriam-Webster Dictionary of English Usage authors then comment:

> Baker’s remarks about *fewer* express clearly and modestly—“I should think,”, “appears to me”—his own taste and preference. It is instructive to compare Baker with one of the most recent college handbooks in our collection:
>
> > *Fewer* refers to quantities that can be counted individually.… *Less* is used for collective quantities that are not counted individually… and for abstract characteristics. —Trimmer & McCrimmon 1988
>
> Notice how Baker’s preference has here been generalized and elevated to an absolute status, and his notice of contrary usage has been omitted. This approach is quite common in handbooks and schoolbooks; many pedagogues seem reluctant to share the often complicated facts about English with their students.
>
> How Baker’s opinion came to be an inviolable rule, we do not know. But we do know that many people believe it is such.

They then give many examples of usage of less for countable quantities, and add finally:

> The examples above show native speakers and writers of English using *less* of count nouns in various constructions. *Fewer* could have been used in many of them—at times it might have been more elegant, as Robert Baker thought—but in others no native speaker would use anything but *less*.

With regards to the example in the original question, either *fewer* or *less* would be perfectly grammatical, but so many people are under the spell of the rule that *less* must never be used with countable nouns that anyone who doesn’t follow the rule may be subject to criticism.

**Edit 2010-09-28:**

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language also weighs in on *less* vs. *fewer*:

> The relation between *less* and *fewer* is fairly complex. In non-count singulars only *less* is possible: *Kim has less/*fewer money than Pat.* In plural NPs we have:
> [17]
> i. *She left less than ten minutes ago.*
> ii. *Less/Fewer than thirty of the students had voted.*
> iii. *He made no less/fewer than fifteen mistakes.*
> iv. *You pass if you make ten mistakes or less/?fewer*.
> v. *He took less/*fewer pains to convince us than I’d expected*.
> vi. *He made fewer/less mistakes than the others.*
>
> Both [i] and [ii] have *than* + numeral. In [i] *ten minutes* expresses an amount of time rather than a number of individuated units, and in such cases *fewer* is virtually impossible—just as *few* would be in a comparison of equality: *She left as little/*few as ten minutes ago.* Similarly with *We paid less than thirty dollars for it; She’s less than forty years old; We were going at less than ten miles an hour.* In [ii] we are concerned with countable individuals and *little* cannot be used in a comparison of equality (**as little as thirty of the students*); nevertheless, for inequality *less* is more common than *fewer* in this construction. The same applies with percentages: *Less/Fewer than 30% of the students had voted.* Construction [iii] has the comparative form following *no*: though the interpretation is count plural, *less* is here again more common than *fewer*. Construction [iv] has *or* after a numeral: *less* is the usual form here, with *fewer* quite marginal; this construction is widely seen in supermarkets, with the fast checkout labelled *eight items or less*, or the like. In [v] *pains* is plural but non-count rather than count (we can’t ask how many pains he took), and here only *less* is possible. Finally in [vi] (as also in [15ii]) the comparative occurs directly with a count plural noun: both forms are found, but *less* is subject to quite strong prescriptavist disapproval, so that *fewer* is widely preferred in formal style, and many speakers in informal style too.
>
> [Usage manuals are divided on the issue of *less* vs. *fewer*. Some uncompromisingly brand such forms as *less mistakes* as incorrect, while others note that though commonly condemned they are often used by speakers of Standard English. Before the Early Modern English period (beginning around 1500) *more* was restricted to non-count NPs with *moe* used as the comparative of *many*. At that time *less* was used along with *fewer* for count NPs, but came to be stigmatised and quite rare in this use: it is only within the last generation or so that it has become frequent. The current revival seems inexorable, given the strong pressure of analogy with *more*.]

Comment: All this is fine, but do you actually recommend "less people" over "fewer people" in the sentence in question?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I don’t recommend either. All I say is “either *fewer* or *less* would be perfectly grammatical” and that if you use *less* you may be subject to undeserved criticism.

Comment: -1.  Fewer is preferred. I don't think Charles Harrington Elster agrees with you.

Comment: @Tim: Charles Harrington Elster, whoever that is, is free to *prefer* whatever he likes. An examination of the evidence, however, makes it quite clear that *less* is perfectly grammatical, and has been for a long time.

Comment: @nohat - Interesting - I would have thought someone interested in the language would recognize his name.  He does know what he is talking about.  For example - http://members.authorsguild.net/chelster/bio.htm  Regardless of my opinions his works are worth reading if you have an interest in the English language.

Comment: Oh yes, I believe I have heard of him. He apparently thinks that you should pronounce *daiquiri* as “DYKE-er-ee” and *minuscule* as “mih-NUSS-kyool”. Yeah, there’s a guy whose opinions should be taken seriously. Try ordering a “strawberry DYKE-er-ee” at a bar and see if you get anything other than funny looks. But sure, YOU know you said it correctly, and that’s what matters!

Comment: @Tim you will notice, for the most part, that my contributions here are not of the sort that “X is standard” and “Y is non-standard” but rather are reports of what usage authorities who base their claims on studying actual usage say as well as my own summaries of actual usage, with the intent that readers can use the information to draw their own conclusions about whether they want to use a particular usage.

Comment: In cases like this, where there is copious evidence that *less* is used in the criticized way frequently in professionally-edited prose by educated writers, and further the supposed “rule” was never a rule but just someone’s suggestion, I feel quite comfortable criticizing the criticizers for their irrational objections, which are based neither on sound historical argument nor on modern common usage, but simply on prescriptive persnicketiness.

Comment: It is all a matter of degree and what you are comfortable with.  If you are afraid of people looking at you funny for pronouncing things correctly then that is your business.

Comment: It’s not fear of funny looks that would stop me from ordering a “DYKE-er-ee”—it’s a fear of failing to communicate. People who are so obsessed with their own notions of language correctness forget that the whole purpose of language is communication.

Comment: @nohat, +1 for the comments. But as [I said](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/322/how-to-answer-questions-about-acceptability/332#332), we need a canonical question/answer (on meta, or in the FAQ) that we can point people to, rather than hashing this out every time.

Comment: @bryn,@nohat: +1 for bryn's pedantness about the pedanticism; and +1 for defeating nohat♦'s usual attitude of unprescriptivinism.

Comment: _**Fewer/less** than a dozen (people)_?

Comment: Garner's fourth edition reads "As a noun, _less_ means “a smaller amount” or “something not as important.” Occasionally, writers make it an adjective when it should be a noun (_“He wants business to make money and everyone to pay less taxes_ [read _less **in** taxes_]). _Less_ for singular nouns or units of measure: _less tonic water, one less golfer, less than six ounces of epoxy_

Answer (score 44):

"Fewer" is used when the actual number of objects is quantifiable.  Since you can count people, "fewer" is correct.

"Less" is used when the amount is not easily quantifiable.  You can put less salt in your soup, for example.

Comment: This is correct. At least, this is how it *ought* to be used — where by "ought" I'm expressing a preference based on my tastes and thinking, and not a rule based on actual English usage (to which we need not be beholden, whatever linguists say). Note, however, that "fewer" calls attention to the enumerable nature of whatever it's describing. Thus "less than eight days" simply means "a period of time less than [eight days]", while "fewer than eight days" suggests "an integer number of days, where the integer is less than 8". Choose carefully.

Comment: Could you please put fewer salt grains in my soup? :)

Comment: That's exactly how I use it. Fewer is for discrete amounts, and less is for relative amounts.

Comment: +1 *Fewer* of things you can have *a few* of, *Less* of things you can have *a little* of.

Comment: @Gareth that's a nice clarification. Otherwise my kid could have less money than Bill Gates, but fewer money than his brother.

Comment: But 'That's one less thing to worry about'. Idioms trump logical patterns.

Comment: _**Fewer/less** than a dozen (people)_?

Comment: Garner's fourth edition reads "As a noun, _less_ means “a smaller amount” or “something not as important.” Occasionally, writers make it an adjective when it should be a noun (_“He wants business to make money and everyone to pay less taxes_ [read _less **in** taxes_]). _Less_ for singular nouns or units of measure: _less tonic water, one less golfer, less than six ounces of epoxy_

Answer (score 18):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has a note about this:

> USAGE *Fewer* versus *less*: strictly speaking, the rule is that *fewer*, the comparative form of *few*, is used with words denoting people or countable things ("fewer members"; "fewer books"; "fewer than ten contestants"). *Less*, on the other hand, is used with mass nouns, denoting things that cannot be counted ("less money"; "less music"). In addition, *less* is normally used with numbers ("less than 10,000") and with expressions of measurement or time ("less than two weeks"; "less than four miles away"). But to use *less* with count nouns, as in "less people" or "less words," is incorrect in standard English.

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Comment: I also think this jibes with my understanding of how the words work. "Less people" is definitely odd, whereas "10 or less" feels correct to me.

Comment: "Less, on the other hand, is used with mass nouns, denoting things that cannot be counted ("less money"; "less music")". This does not make sense. I **can** count my money.

Comment: @DavidPostill _Money_ is a mass noun, so generally nobody says _1 money, two moneys, three moneys_. When you check how much money you have, you are probably going to say _I have three dollars_ or _I have four euros_, which is correct.

Comment: _**Fewer/less** than a dozen (people)_?

Answer (score 7):

[Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/less-versus-fewer.aspx) wrote about this, and putting it very succintly, the differences between "few" and "less":

> Less and fewer are easy to mix up. They mean the same thing—the opposite of more—but you use them in different circumstances. The basic rule is that you use less with mass nouns and fewer with count nouns.

So, what is a count noun, and a mass noun?

> A count noun is just something you can count. I'm looking at my desk and I see books, pens, and M&M's. I can count all those things, so they are count nouns and the right word to use is fewer. I should eat fewer M&M's.
>
> Mass nouns are just things that you can't count individually. Again, on my desk I see tape and clutter. These things can't be counted individually, so the right word to use is less. If I had less clutter, my desk would be cleaner. **Another clue is that you don't make mass nouns plural**: I would never say I have clutters on my desk or that I need more tapes to hold my book covers together.

I have added that emphasis because it points out a lot. This makes identifying Mass nouns very easy.

What about your example, in which you said "**Less** than 9 sausages?" Isn't that, a violation of this rule? Shouldn't "few" be used?

The fact is, there is the word *than*, which changes everything. When there is a "than", the sentence is changed into a comparison, and  "less" is used when making comparisons. According to the [Chicago Style Manual](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/LessorFewer/LessorFewer01.html):

> Less than is used before a plural noun that denotes a measure of time, amount, or distance: *less than three weeks; less than $400; less than 50 miles.*

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/grammartiplessorfewer) surprisingly helps us with this:

> Less is also used with numbers when they are on their own and with expressions of measurement or time, e.g.:
>
> His weight fell from 18 stone to less than 12.
>   Their marriage lasted less than two years.
>   Heath Square is less than four miles away from Dublin city centre

That's why "less" was used, when referring to "9 sausages".

Examples of usage of "less than" includes:

> I have **less** pencils **than** you.
>   We all have **less** reputation **than** Robusto.
>   The increase was **less than** the decrease.
>   I have **less than** 5 dollars in my pocket.
>   We have **less than** 2 hours to accomplish this.

Finishing off, with a quote from Grammar Girl, this notes the **exceptions** to the rules:

> There are exceptions to these rules; for example, it is customary to use the word less to describe time, money, and distance. For example, you could say, “That wedding reception lasted less than two hours. I hope they paid the band less than $400.” So keep in mind that time, money, and distance are different, but if you stick with the quick and dirty tip that less is for mass nouns and fewer is for count nouns, you'll be right most of the time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That makes sense - I understand the rules - but is there a *reason* why the "than" changes it, other than that's what the CMS says? Also, would you say "*less* sausages than there were before" or "*fewer* sausages than there were before" (i.e. comparing but not to a number)?

Comment: I think you've made a mistake here. I'm pretty sure it should be FEWER pencils. My understanding, and an alternate way to explain the exception, is that "less" can be used in place of "fewer" when comparing things with continous values (time, distance, weight) rather than discrete values (number of sausages, number of pencils). Also, I don't believe the use of "less than" applies to sausages, unless you are talking about food or meat in general, and "9 sausages" refers to the amount of food or meat equivalent to 9 sausages. Otherwise you are counting indiviudal items, and should use "fewer".

Comment: *Pam has the **fewest** pencils, 3. Pat has the **smallest** pencils, and he has 4. **Who has the least pencils?** [BBC: "*least* is the superlative form of *little/not much* and *fewest* is the superlative form of *few/not many*."](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv260.shtml) The association *fewer/few/fewest* is maybe one reason that *less*, though gaining on *fewer* for countables, still tends to be limited to measure/magnitude/size. It perhaps restrains the movement away from what has been the majority usage, aka the "rule" that descriptivists decry.

Comment: _**Fewer/less** than a dozen (people)_?

Comment: Garner's fourth edition reads "As a noun, _less_ means “a smaller amount” or “something not as important.” Occasionally, writers make it an adjective when it should be a noun (_“He wants business to make money and everyone to pay less taxes_ [read _less **in** taxes_]). _Less_ for singular nouns or units of measure: _less tonic water, one less golfer, less than six ounces of epoxy_

Answer (score 6):

British Supermarkets are split on whether to describe express checkouts as '10 items or less' (Tesco) or '10 items or fewer' (Marks & Spencer). Seemingly the more upmarket chains use 'fewer' and the more mainstream chains using 'less'.

As to which is the correct usage I would agree with Scott Handelman:

> "Fewer" is used when the actual number of objects is quantifiable. Since you can count people, "fewer" is correct.
>
> "Less" is used when the amount is not easily quantifiable. You can put less salt in your soup, for example.

Comment: An excellent illustration in the variation in usage across social registers, which sadly will probably be lost in anyone not versed in the socioeconomic structure of British grocery retail.

Comment: So it seems that less people are using fewer.

Comment: That probably depends on the interpretation: you could argue that you have "Ten items of shopping, or FEWER items of shopping", or you have "Ten items of shopping or LESS shopping (than ten items)". I'm not saying that this is what the sign-writers thought, but it is a possible explanation why both can be correct.

Comment: _**Fewer/less** than a dozen (people)_?

Comment: Garner's fourth edition reads "As a noun, _less_ means “a smaller amount” or “something not as important.” Occasionally, writers make it an adjective when it should be a noun (_“He wants business to make money and everyone to pay less taxes_ [read _less **in** taxes_]). _Less_ for singular nouns or units of measure: _less tonic water, one less golfer, less than six ounces of epoxy_

Answer (score 2):

I remember it like this:

- Less cake (e.g. I ate less cake then I wanted)
- Fewer cakes (e.g. I ate fewer cakes than I wanted)

Less of one thing - fewer of many things.

P.S. Mmmm cake :)

Answer (score 2):

Strunk's 1918 edition of *[The Elements of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style)* confirms that less is for multitude nouns and fewer is for countable nouns in the [Misused Expressions](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk3.html#23) section. So does the Chicago Manual of Style (to which I cannot link, because it's subscription only).

Of course there are disagreements as detailed above by @nohat, but those are a couple of well-respected style guides that can give some guidance to those of a prescriptivist bent.

Comment: Strunk & White are not well-respected where I come from. http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497

Comment: ..and a response, also from the Chronicle: http://chronicle.com/blogPost/StrunkWhite-Endure/6926/

"...we should wonder why linguists react so angrily to positions that smack of prescriptivism."

I believe The Elements of Style is still fairly well-respected outside of the linguist camp.

Comment: It's still full of errors, hypocrisy, and vacuous advice. They can’t even identify the passive voice correctly. Why should anyone take writing advice from someone who literally doesn’t know what they’re talking about?

Comment: well, I'm not trying to convince you of anything, nohat, just to point out, in the interest of balance, that the opinion you reference isn't the last word on the subject.

Comment: What shocked me was hearing the phrase "less troups" on BBC World News.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "fewer people"; and it is indeed linked to count vs uncount nouns. 'People' is countable, unlike water, as you can talk about "three people did x". So I'd disagree with Noldorin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a mathematician's point of view:

use "fewer" for integer quantities (anything that can be counted)

use "less" for real quantities (anything that can be measured)

Comment: "1 is fewer than 2" definitely sounds like correct usage to me.

Comment: @cindi Your example doesn't define what you're counting or measuring so it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @Gary, it would be interesting to know what English (regional) dialect you speak. To my Southern Californian ears, "1 is less than 2" sounds correct, whereas "1 is fewer than 2" sounds (to me) to be in the same class as "there is one dogs."

Comment: @BryanH 2 mistakes is less/fewer than 5, but only 2 is less than 5. Numbers are hardly regular count nouns.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that *less* is being used where *fewer* was once common. It will become dominant and then invariant within the next 10-20 years. I see *less + countable* nouns all the time in print and on TV lately. Language change in action. http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2819

Comment: Looking at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+words%2Cfewer+words&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cless%20words%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfewer%20words%3B%2Cc0), it doesn't look like *less* will overtake *fewer* any time soon.

Comment: @Peter Yes, you can't say there are less people using _fewer_.

Answer (score -2):

In this particular case the correct word to use is 'less', since 'people' is a mass/collective noun. It is commonly used as the plural form of 'person'. I consider this grammatically incorrect (undoubtedly it was so traditionally) though modern usage has adopted it as a sort of plural form.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/page/150) explains the usage cases of 'less' and 'fewer' pretty well:

> Use fewer if you’re referring to people or things in the plural (e.g. houses, newspapers, dogs, students, children). For example:
>   * People these days are buying fewer newspapers.
>   * Fewer students are opting to study science-related subjects.
>   * Fewer than thirty children each year develop the disease.
>
> Use less when you’re referring to something that can’t be counted or doesn’t have a plural (e.g. money, air, time, music, rain). For example:
>   * It’s a better job but they pay you less money.
>   * People want to spend less time in traffic jams.
>   * Ironically, when I’m on tour, I listen to less music.

Comment: Er, sorry, no. "People" isn't a non-count noun. "Fewer people" sounds right to me and "less people" actually *doesn't*, while "fewer" doesn't work at all with your other examples you claim to be parallel to "people": you can't say "fewer money", "fewer time" or "fewer music". See also kiamlaluno's answer quoting the New Oxford American Dictionary which explicitly says "less people" is incorrect in standard English!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It can be either depending on the situation, but historically people was a mass-noun (or count known when talking about populations). Its usage has been corrupted in recent times such that it has become a plural for "person", so in that sense it's also acceptable. I am however a traditionalist, and this is reflected in my answer. See nohat's answer, which gives a full explanation.

Comment: People is a count noun, and has been for quite a while. See this [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=three+people%2Cthree+persons&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=20).

Comment: @Peter: Note it only became *predominant* in the 70s. Taking into account the fact that historical data pre 1700 is of small size, it's pretty obvious that traditionally "3 persons" was gramatically and semantically correct. "3 people" just doesn't make sense considering the historical usages and etymology!

Comment: @Noldorin: etymology != meaning. People is the plural of person and has been for long enough that fighting it is pointless.

Comment: Of course not heh; they're orthogonal concepts. Etymology *tells* you about the history of meaning. Language always evolves and people always resist change. In this case I think we've *lost* precision and differentiation (originally) through ignorance. English is surely one of the most ambiguous languages on Earth today.