# Mass nouns and counts nouns. Does getting it wrong ever matter?

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives, uncountable-nouns

Less/fewer, too much/too many, amount/number... When people get these things wrong, it bugs me. But I cannot think of a situation where mistaking a mass noun for a count noun (or vice versa) would ever introduce any kind of ambiguity.

Is there such a case?

Comment: The less/fewer and amount/number dichotomies are false ones — they are not reflected in usage.  (Yes, there is a tendency, and yes, there are certain cases where only one works, but it is not a nice clean split.)  At some point in time, when prescriptive rules to make language "more logical" were all the rage, *recommendations* like these were pushed forward.  Some people mistakenly believe them to be actual grammatical rules of English, which they are not.  I say, if this recommendation did not take hold after over a hundred years, then the suggested "logical" dichotomy was just not optimal.

Comment: @Kosmonaut I like how you criticise prescriptive rules of grammar, but then categorically deny that the less/fewer distinction has any content while still admitting it has some basis in usage. Way to undermine your own point. [p.s. who said grammatical rules had to be unambiguously dichotomous?]

Comment: @Seamus My point is that when it bugs you that people get it "wrong", they aren't getting it "wrong" in these cases.  Your annoyance implies that you don't like the ones that don't fall into place — why else would you be bugged by it?  These places where people are "wrong" are the usages that just don't fit this arbitrarily overreaching rule.

Comment: @Kosmonaut There's quite a lot cases where people use "less" when they are talking about something that is obviously, unambiguously a count noun (e.g. people), and it's these obvious cases where it sounds wrong to me. Personally, I think it's possible, in most cases to decide whether something is a mass noun and when it's a count noun. So I don't think this rule is really that "overreaching". Also, by "it bugs me" I mean "it sounds wrong to me" not "these people are wrong".

Comment: If you only meant to say it sounds wrong *to you*, why didn't you give specific examples in your question?  It definitely sounds like you are taking for granted that these are universally regarded as errors.  The way that *much/many* works just doesn't precisely correspond to *less/fewer* and *amount/number*.  People aren't miscalculating whether something is a count noun or not, they just aren't applying such a neat rule as you are describing.  Some discussion here: http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003775.html

Comment: The thing is that *less* has been used with count nouns for hundreds of years. The idea that it cannot be used with them was made up in the 18th century, and has never reflected the way the language is actually used, not now, not then, not ever. See my answer here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505

Comment: @Kosmonaut It sounds wrong to me _because_ I have effectively internalised the mass noun/count noun distinction and the associated less/fewer rule. This was a question I asked to try and understand whether this rule ever made a difference. Culinary examples notwithstanding, I think the answer is "not really". Despite this, I'm going to carry on using "less" with mass nouns and "fewer" with count nouns, because to do otherwise would sound wrong to me.

Comment: @nohat That the rule was made up, and more or less stringently enforced has meant that language has changed. I'm not prescriptivist enough to say that the rule _should_ be enforce (nor that it shouldn't) but to suggest that usage of less/fewer is completely blind to the distinction is just not true. Almost all uses of "fewer" will be with count nouns, the majority of uses of "less" will be with mass nouns, regardless of whether it "really should" be a rule or not.

Comment: @Seamus "That the rule was made up, and more or less stringently enforced has meant that language has changed." But this mass/count dichotomy never happened — the language did not change.  *Fewer* has always just worked with count nouns; but no native speaker ever gets this wrong.  So, can you give an example of a usage that bugs you?  Make this restriction on yourself if you want — but I will always object if someone characterizes centuries-old usage as a mistake because they didn't follow a grammarian's suggestion that never reflected English usage at any point in history.

Comment: I think there's a perfectly good, perfectly well understood (if sometimes vague) distinction between mass nouns and count nouns. It's vacuously true that this hasn't always been the case: there was a time when English did not exist. So what? There is, now, a well understood distinction. I don't think this is the dispute anyway. It's about whether using "less" with count nouns is always "wrong" (insofar as anything is "wrong" in grammar - like I said, I'm no prescriptivist). As for an example: "There are less people here than I expected" sounds wrong to my ear.

Comment: @Seamus no one is claiming there is no distinction between mass and count nouns. What we are saying is that *less* (like *more*) has always been applicable to both mass and count nouns. The “rule” saying that *less* can’t be applied to count nouns was made up and has never been true of how the language works, nor has it been stringently enforced by anyone other than some deluded English teachers. The MDEU entry gives copious examples of how *less* is used with mass nouns in a perfectly grammatical way all the time: http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PA592&pg=PA593

Comment: @nohat The Economist style guide, the Guardian style guide and Strunk and White all advocate the rule. That's hardly just "some deluded English teachers". Fowler is uncharacteristically silent and the OED allows that less is a comparative that can apply to quantity. It is interesting to note that most of the MDEU examples are massy concepts expressed in discrete units "no less than 10,000 miles"; large numbers; or the construction "no less than", the first and third of which don't strike me as wrong sounding.

Comment: http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497

Comment: Style guides provide *guidance* on what they believe is the best style, not judgment on what is and is not grammatical English. Indeed I agree *fewer* is better style than *less* with count nouns, but that doesn’t make use of *less* somehow an error or “wrong”. Let’s not confuse style advice with grammatical correctness.

Comment: It's simply false to claim that style guides aren't a guide to proper grammar. Good style guides should mention those aspects of grammar that are frequently abused. There is no "definitive rulebook" for grammar, so an exhortation not to do something in things like these style guides is the closest grammar gets to saying something is wrong. Just because the rule is new that doesn't mean it isn't legitimate. 50 years ago "email" wasn't a word, that doesn't mean it isn't now a legit word. (I guess the obvious rebuttal is that there isn't a _consensus_ among modern authorities on less/fewer)

Comment: @Seamus You have confused informal style with ungrammaticality. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* notes “The standard language embraces a range of styles, from formal through neutral to informal. A satisfactory grammar must describe them all. It is not that formal style keeps to the rules and informal style departs from them; rather, formal and informal styles have partially different rules” (p.8). It is clear that *less* used with count nouns is part of the grammar, and describing it as “wrong” or an aspect of grammar that is “frequently abused” is mistaken.

Comment: Given the myriad ways English is (ab)used in "the informal style" (whatever that means), I don't think there's any sense in which this informal style has a grammar. Otherwise you have to accept "Where was you last night?" as grammatical, since it's an often used informal construction. This makes a mockery of what grammar is supposed to be about. It's only in relatively formal contexts (when it is accepted that there are rules and they should be more or less adhered to) that grammar makes sense. And "less" being restricted to mass nouns is at least a candidate for being a rule.

Comment: @Seamus, you’re incorrect. Informal English, like any variety (such as e.g. African-American Vernacular English), is governed by rules which can be described by grammar. To take your example, perhaps in some varieties “Where was you?” is grammatical, but in no variety is “Where am you?” grammatical. Why? Because there is a rule of grammar at work. Even languages spoken only by illiterate people have rules of grammar. There is nothing special about standard formal English other than it being one set of grammar rules you learn in school that constitute a formal style.

Comment: I'm fine with that. You seemed to be suggesting that grammar was what applied to all styles/registers/what have you. Rather than that different varieties have different rules. So there is a "style" (or some styles) where the less/fewer distinction is valid. And if people misuse it when in this style, they are _wrong_. This seemed to be a claim that you were denying earlier...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are correct in that if a noun is unambiguously mass or count then the qualifier doesn't matter, the meaning can be taken from the noun.

However compare: I ate too much fish vs. I ate too many fish.

If the noun is ambiguous in that way, then the meaning must be taken from the qualifier. So if you mistook "fish" for a term that was always mass or common, then you could produce an ambiguous statement.

(Inspired by Shinto's example)

Comment: I think that's a pretty harmless example of confusion. In either case, too much fish was eaten. Whether or not this was in the form of an over-large tuna steak or too many whitebait is a pretty flimsy reason to establish such a far reaching linguistic convention. Is that the best you've got? ;)

Answer (score 8):

The classic example (which is probably an urban myth) is a foreign learner saying "I ate a chicken last night" when he meant "I ate some chicken last night". Mistaking chicken (the meat) for a countable noun makes it sound like he ate an entire bird.

Comment: lots of people eat [almost] entire birds, though... :)

Comment: Perhaps replacing "chicken" with "turkey" would give a better example.  Eating a whole chicken is plausible, especially if it's a small one.  Eating a whole turkey would be a prodigious feat.

Answer (score 4):

Some words have different meanings depending on count/ noncount usage.  If you turn in "a paper", it means you have given the teacher an assignment, while simply having "some paper" means you have plain paper with nothing on it.  I have two papers, means I have two assignments.  I have two pieces of paper means I have two pages. I have a chicken means I have a bird, and I have some chicken means I have some bird meat.

Most words only have one meaning and usage, so confusing the two just sounds awkward rather than truly confusing like the paper and chicken examples.

Comment: So misuse of "too much" with count nouns is much rarer, but I can see an argument for "I have too much papers" being a possible case of confusion. But it's still the case that whether "paper" is plural or not decides between the cases, no? "I have too much paper" [mass] vs "I have too much papers" [assignments]

Answer (score 2):

I was recently in a grocery store where the express lane was marked "10 Items or Fewer."  I made a mental note that that was a classy chain, so in a marketing sense, getting it right made a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't enroll in Tattooing 101 because you have too many classes.  You can't enroll in Tattooing 101 because you have too much class.

You cannot make too many glasses if you don't have much glass.  You can make fewer glasses if you have less glass.  You can only make a little glass if you only have a little glass.

My uncle has too much wood in his cabinet shop; there's not enough space left for a new planer.  My uncle has too many woods in his cabinet shop; there's no need for him to stock zebra wood.

My sister doesn't like that radio station; she says it has too much blues.  My sister doesn't like that wallpaper; she says it has too much blue.  My sister doesn't like that wallpaper; she says it has too many blues.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real life example.

1. "Here's a box full of books, most of them are quite good. Here's another box. It has **less** good books in."
2. "Here's a box full of books, most of them are quite good. Here's another box. It has **fewer** good books in."

(1) feels like it should be parsed as follows: "It has [less good] books in". That is, the books in the box are of (uniformly?) lower quality. "less good" is behaving like a compound adjective.
(2) on the other hand, seems to suggest "It has fewer [good books] in". "Good books" is behaving like a compound noun. The suggestion this time is that the books are possibly of similar quality, it's just that the box isn't as full: there are fewer books.