# 'less' is to 'fewer' as 'more' is to what?

Tags: word-choice, analogy

This question is related to the [previous one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer) on less-vs-fewer. I prefer using *fewer* instead of *less* when referring to discrete items. Something sounds off about *less than ten people*, in my opinion.

But what about the flip side? The phrase *more than ten people* doesn't sound quite right either. If *less* and *more* are natural antonyms, then what word relates to *more* the same way *fewer* relates to *less*?

Answer (score 34):

There is no distinction: *less* is to *fewer* as *more* is to *more*.

- *more* water; *less* water
- *more* dogs; *less/fewer* dogs
- 10 items or *more*; 10 items or *less/fewer*
- one *more* bell to answer; one *less* bell to answer
- weighing 100 pounds *more*; weighing 100 pounds *less*
- 500 words or *more*; 500 words or *less*
- *more* than 10,000 miles; *less* than 10,000 miles

Comment: And if that doesn’t highlight the pointlessness of the less/fewer distinction, I don’t know what does.

Comment: @Jason, see [my answer to a previous question about less/fewer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer/505#505) for why your analysis is off the mark.

Comment: @nohat Actually, if you check the New Oxford English dictionary, they are pretty clear on the rules: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/page/150. There are also some pretty reputable sources denoting the difference here: http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/less-versus-fewer.aspx, and here: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adjectives.htm, and other various places in style books and all over the internet. Now this becomes a religious debate: which dictionary is right? Yours because you say it is or mine because I say it is? Remember, a dictionary is written by people who have opinions too.

Comment: @nohat, I read your answer to question 495 before asking this one. It's a good answer. You make a strong case that in real usage, there's not much difference between 'less' and 'fewer'.  But some of us just can't bring ourselves to say 'less dogs'.

Comment: @I.J. I do fear I haven’t fully answered your question, or at least I haven’t fully made clear that I’m not claiming that there is no distinction to be made between *less* and *fewer* (there is a distinction between those words)—just that the matching superior comparator is *more* for both.

Comment: @nohat - interesting argument, "correct usage is decided by users of the language, not by self-appointed arbiters of correctness." "users of the language": i guess "almost every usage writer" and "flocks of english teachers" (quoted from your MW source) don't count as users of the language, nor the students learning from these people. also, by "self-appointed arbiters of correctness" do you mean, um, dictionaries? i'll give you another try if you'd like.

Comment: @Jason you misunderstand. It is not decided by what people say, such as usage writers or English teachers, but by what people *do*, by doing real analysis of large corpora of texts.

Comment: @slim you should send Hal David a firmly worded letter then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Less_Bell_to_Answer

Answer (score 3):

less is to fewer as greater is to more

Comment: Surely, "less is to fewer as more is to greater"? Even so, I can't buy this. "There are greater apples in this bowl than in the other"? Nope. Perhaps "There is a greater number of apples in this bowl than in the other"? But what an awkward construction.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that, in principle, 'less' relates to uncountable nouns and 'fewer' relates to countable nouns. However, the concept in the mind of the speaker has an influence. We can say 'less than a thousand miles' because the concept in the mind of the speaker, is *distance*, which is not countable. Similarly, bridge players often assess the strenth of their hand by points but it does not offend me to hear 'I had less than ten points' because the concept in the mind of the speaker is *strength*, not *points*.

Comment: Good answer, but I think your second point needs tidying up. The 'concept in the mind of the speaker' must be the same as the concept expressed (if you are using language properly), and you could only travel  *?fewer than a thousand miles* if you had seven-league boots, or some other contrivance that cannot go a smaller distance than a mile.

Answer (score 0):

As nohat pointed out, the distinction does not exist for more. As far as I understand it, it could be said "'less' is to 'fewer' as 'much' is to 'many'" though.

Comment: Late comment I know, but 'many' is an adjective, not a comparison
You wouldn't say 'the are many apples in this bowl than the other' when comparing it to another bowl - the other bowl may also have many apples.
Instead, you can say 'this bowl has many more apples than the other' to show there is a large difference'

Comment: @cyberspy that is true, it was more of a tangent maybe.

Answer (score 0):

We do say "less than, greater than" but other than adding "even" we don't really change "more" to fit the noun. "We have even more people here today than yesterday" or "We have a greater number of people here today than yesterday." Those are both comparisons. If you didn't want to compare and if you didn't want to use "more" then you could potentially say "We have a great number of people." That one could be confusing though because it could be any number that your personal opinion deems as great, rather than "great" meaning a large number, so in that case it might be better to say "We have a lot of people" or "We have many people..."

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated already, ‘more’ is the opposite of both ‘fewer’ and ‘less’. But I would like to suggest English take after their cousin Swedish (my native language).

In Swedish we have:
 - less/more = mindre/mer
 - fewer/more = färre/fler

So my suggestion is English use the word ‘flore’ to mean ‘more objects’. This of course makes it easy to confuse with ‘floor’ and to mend this, I suggest ‘floor’ gets replaced by the Swedish counterpart ‘golv’.

Comment: Neology is sisyphean.