# Is "many fewer combinations" correct?

Tags: expression-choice

Is the expression "many fewer combinations" correct?  It only gets about 600 hits on Google, against 1,200 for "a lot fewer combinations".  What would be a correct way of expressing the idea contained in "many fewer combinations"?  would it be best rephrased using something like "a large reduction in the number of combinations", or something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is "less" appropriate vs. "fewer"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/when-is-less-appropriate-vs-fewer)

Comment: @Robusto Although certainly related, I don't think this is a duplicate as it's asking about a different issue (specifically, much vs. many and which is used with "fewer").

Comment: @rintaun: No worries. Folks seem to agree with you, so the question is more than likely to remain open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that the expression "many fewer combinations" is **perfectly acceptable** and should be understood just fine. As there is some disagreement on this, however, it may be preferable to use a different expression. Some examples of alternates follow.

> - "a lot fewer" - As you suggest, this is correct; however it *is* somewhat more informal-sounding, which may or may not be right for your situation.
> - "far fewer" - [This post on alt.usage.english](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.usage.english/msg/eaae1f9f3d0f5448?pli=1) suggests that "far fewer" rose in popularity *due to* the confusion between *much* and *many* fewer.
> - "significantly fewer" - As strangeronyourtrain suggests in his answer, this seems to be a very good choice, and can be used in many different contexts.
> - There are also an endless number of ways this could be rephrased, rather than simply changing "many." Your own example of "a large reduction in the number of combinations" seems fine (if a bit wordy).

---

Regarding the disagreement about many or much fewer, [in this discussion](http://www.englishforums.com/English/MuchFewerOrManyFewer/dzpzb/post.htm), it is contended *fewer* is an adjective, and thus the adverb *much* must be used over the determiner *many*. In my opinion, this is actually a misunderstanding of the function of the word *fewer*; it is in fact, a determiner itself, not an adjective.

Basically, because "combination" is a countable noun, you use *many* and *fewer* to describe it. Uncountable nouns such as "sand" and "water," on the other hand, are described with the words *much* and *less*.

However, [Google's NGram Viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=many+fewer%2Cmuch+fewer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=2) shows that while "many fewer" has been in use for quite a while, it did not become the preferred usage until about 1960. This may be due to the reasoning above, and the growth of "many fewer" may be a result of hypercorrection, as Tragicomic suggested in a comment.

Comment: But nobody would disagree with "many more", would they?

Comment: @Urbycoz: You're right. Actually I take back that comment. Based on what @Rintaun says, "Many fewer combinations" should be fine. However, it sounds like hypercorrection to me. Is "many fewer combinations" really perfectly acceptable in normal usage (over "much fewer combinations")? There seems to be a lot of discussion about this all over the internet. I had always thought "much fewer" to be acceptable usage.

Comment: I think the reason people seem to be uncomfortable with "many fewer" is that in one pair of meanings "many" and "fewer" are close to opposites. But I don't think there's anything either ungrammatical or ambiguous about it.

Comment: I'd be careful about *significantly fewer* in some contexts, since it may imply something about *statistical significance*, which both would require backing up, and also may not actually be a "lot" fewer, just enough fewer to be statistically significant (i.e. non-negligible).

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions that are less awkward about quantifying the quantifier:

- *far fewer combinations than*
- *significantly fewer combinations than*
- *not nearly as many combinations as*
- *much more uniform than* (I don't know if this phrasing suits your context—it's just a guess)

Comment: Interesting.  The original sentence is something like "… because we now have many fewer combinations".  I can see "far fewer combinations than in the past" being a possible wording; I wonder if one could do without an explicit comparison, though.

Comment: Nice suggestions, but am I wrong that this doesn't answer the main question?

Answer (score 0):

the word "fewer" already holds a comparative meaning of being less than "few"
considering you mean to say something like "I had few options", "now I have fewer", the word "fewer" alone is enough to signify this. If you want to emphasize a great difference between "few" and "fewer", my suggestion is that you could use "even fewer"