# "See less events" or "see fewer events"

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Less” vs. “fewer”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)

I'm placing a button on a website and need to know which is the proper way to write this out: *see less events* or *see fewer events*? I'm leaning toward *fewer* but would like confirmation.

Comment: See [@nohats answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/505/17956)

Answer (score 3):

***Fewer*** is appropriate because *event* is a [countable noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun).

Comment: Sorry @combread ninja, but your answer is completely wrong. I voted down.

Comment: @RégisRoux: Why do you say it is _wrong_? It is the rule taught in school (but it is commonly not used).

Comment: Yes @Mitch, fewer means "of smaller number," but only 'less' emphasize quantity; I think the OP have to emphasize the quantity, not the number.

Comment: @RégisRoux, I don't really know what you mean. As such, in its current form, your comment is nonsensical.

Comment: @Alex B. Sorry, I do not understand why my comment is nonsensical.

Comment: Simple and succinct, but includes why to use "fewer". +1

Comment: @RégisRoux: can you be more clear as to how 'quantity' and 'number' are different? Especially with respect to 'events' (in the original question)?

Comment: @Mitch - It should be considerd I'm't native, however I think the user of button will not interested on the number of events: it is irrelevant whether they are 100 or 1000. What is relevant is that the events are less on more.

Comment: @RégisRoux: OK. If you're a non-native speaker, how can you be so sure that the poster is 'completely wrong? In English, the distinction you're drawing between quantity and number __in this context__ doesn't hold. The rule is: 'less' is for  non-integral quantities/numbers, 'fewer' is for integral ones. Also, even though I called it a rule, it is not particularly closely followed in practice. See the duplicate question for details.

Comment: @Mitch - Yes you are right. Pheraps I was been rather ... (I put the ellips because I do not know the word). Next time I will think better after posting a comment.

Comment: @RégisRoux - "before" might be more useful than "after".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, fewer would be most proper.