# Is "as little as one" grammatical or should it always be "as few as one" since 'one' implies the thing is countable?

Tags: grammar

I've used the phrase "as few as one individual from the business has contact with the customer" in a paper and the more I look at it, the more wrong it looks! But "as little as one individual" doesn't seem any better. I can count 'individuals' i.e. people, so should it be 'as few as'? If anyone can rephrase this without using either less or fewer that would also solve the problem!

Comment: _Only_ one individual.

Comment: It's not only "grammatical" - *to as **little** as one* has almost always been [significantly more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+as+few+as+one%2Cto+as+little+as+one&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20as%20few%20as%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20as%20little%20as%20one%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20as%20few%20as%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20as%20little%20as%20one%3B%2Cc0) than *to as **few** as one*. But in your *exact* context I'd go for something like ***Sometimes only one** individual from the business [blah blah]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That doesn't take into account differences in countable/uncountable usages, where *few* is used for countable and *little* for uncountable. Also idiomatic usages like "as little as one spoonful" (measuring quantity, so uncountable even though spoonsful are countable).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: True, but the first part of my comment was just to give the lie to OP's "the more I look at it, the more wrong it looks" as regards just those 5 words. They're not *actually* "wrong" - they just don't suit OP's exact context. And although there are several written instances of [*as **little** as one spoonful*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+little+as+one+spoonful%22) in Google Books, there are none at all for [*as **few** as one spoonful*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+few+as+one+spoonful%22), so maybe "countable / uncountable" is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Andrew Leach '_few_ is used for countable and _little_ for uncountable [situations]' Not always, at least the first part. The idiomaticity of each individual expression needs looking at.

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially @FumbleFingers, very helpful :) - also good to know there's a bit of ambiguity/flexibility here regarding the less/fewer rule

Comment: Stretching a point, perhaps, but does this answer your question? [Is "I've told you at fewest ten times" grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148071/is-ive-told-you-at-fewest-ten-times-grammatical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would the parallel word appear?

*As much as 10 and as little as one*. (Both "much" and "little" seem wrong here.)

*As many as 10 and as few as one.* (This sounds fine to me.)

Answer (score -1):

There are several possibilities.

- merely one individual…
- no more than one individual
- a sole individual

Comment: None of these mean the same thing as 'as little/few as one individual' which has the meaning, 1 person is the least amount, but there can potentially be more.