# "Fewer resources" or "less resources"?

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns

I was writing a document in Microsoft Word, and it flagged "less resources" as being ungrammatical and suggested "fewer resources".  I did some research, and it appears that "fewer resources" seems to be used more often, and one commenter on another English usage site said this was correct.  But this seems odd to me.  I try to be diligent about using "fewer" with countable nouns; a phrase like "The software has less bugs than it did last week" just grates on me.  But even though "resources" is a plural and thus looks like a countable noun, it doesn't seem as though it should be, logically.  If I were to write a business analysis that said "Plan A requires fewer resources than Plan B", would that mean that, say, Plan A would require only 15 resources while Plan B might require 17?  This doesn't make sense.  But is it possible for a noun such as this to be considered countable, grammatically, even though it makes no sense to use it with an actual count?

Comment: Microsoft Word grammar checker can't check for actual grammar; it just notices that this is plural in form. Turn it off; it's full of zombies. BTW, _fewer resources_ is quite reasonable; that means fewer varieties and sources of resources, under these circumstances.

Comment: You may find useful this link: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/less-or-fewer

Comment: @JohnLawler If it were only MS Word saying this, I would have ignored it, but some other research seemed to point in the same direction.  But my thoughts about that other research fell on the floor somehow.  I've edited my post.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Related: *[“Less” vs. “fewer”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495)*

Answer (score 4):

In standard grammar "few/fewer" is connected with a plural noun and "little" ( meaning not much) and "less" with singular of uncountables.
As a non-native speaker I can't judge whether people in spoken language really observe this rule. It might be that people often use less + plural because they consider this differentiation as impractial for everyday language. English has too many words and it is the only language of the ones I know that makes such an unnecessary distinction.

The funny thing is that French peu (not much/not many), the origin of few, can be connected with singular and plural.

It seems that in the past some grammarian of renown suggested that "little" should be used with singular and "few" with plural and somehow this suggestion became a grammar rule. Actually a rule that complicates the system and I think that people who don't observe this invented rule simply try to make the system easier.

Comment: _Few_ does not come from French. It is a Germanic word (though it is of course related to French _peu_). The distinction between _little/less_ and _few(er)_ is common to most older Germanic languages (but has been lost in some).

Comment: According to etymonline the source is Latin paucus/a/um and plural pauci meaning not big in number. And Latin paucum/pauci gave French peu, so in Dauzat, etymology, and from the English pronunciation of few I take it that the word came into English via French.

Comment: That is not what etymonline says. It says the word is from a PIE root _*pau-_ (questionable reconstruction, but that doesn't matter for current purposes), and that cognates in other PIE branches include Latin _paucus_. The English word comes directly from the PIE source, not from Latin. The fact that the word has an f in all Germanic languages is actually proof that it didn't come from Latin (and _certainly_ not French!), since Grimm's Law happened before Latin ever came into contact with the Germanic languages.

Comment: For me it is not interesting where the word comes from. The nearest occurrence for me is Latin paucum, pauci. In questions as to Proto-Germanic or Indo-European or even PIE I not so much interested. I can't verify it, there are too many constructions and assumptions. -  What about Latin pater and English father?

Comment: What about them? They too share a common ancestor in PIE, but English did not borrow it from Latin. _To bear_ and _ferō_ are the same, as are _fish_ and _piscis_, _warm_ and _formus_, etc. If you’re looking for close cognates of ‘few’, look within Germanic: Icelandic [_fár_](http://digicoll.library.wisc.edu/cgi-bin/IcelOnline/IcelOnline.TEId-idx?type=entry&eid=FA1R-2&q1=f%E1r), for example, which directly continues the Old Norse form, or Gothic _fawai_, or Old High German _fao_.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Fewer%20resources,%20Less%20resources,%20fewer%20resources,%20less%20resources&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Fewer%20resources;,c0;.t1;,Less%20resources;,c0;.t1;,fewer%20resources;,c0;.t1;,less%20resources;,c0) *fewer resources* is a much more used expression compared to *less resources*.

Answer (score -3):

The *less* versus *fewer* 'rule' is total BS. No-one ever has a problem with *more* being applicable to both count and non-count nouns (e.g. 'more children', 'more whisky') -- why, then, the ridiculous fuss about insisting on *fewer* instead of *less* for count nouns? If it were me, I would completely ignore MS Word's 'correction', which has no basis in anything except a stupid rule invented by prescriptivist grammaticasters.

Comment: This question is not asking about what is understandable, but what is grammatically correct according to the standards of the English language.

Comment: "Grammatically correct according to the standards of the English language"??? That's the most pompous bit of pontification I've yet encountered today. How about applying the standard of "sensible, logical and idiomatic" instead?

Comment: It's true that the traditional *less* versus *fewer* rule is descriptively inadequate.  However, that doesn't mean the two are fully interchangeable.  This answer could be improved by telling us what the rule is, not just what the rule isn't.  See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* p.1126-7 for one description.

Comment: I like the view and wording of Erich Kowal. Courageous, but I think Erich has a point.

Comment: The count distinction between _little/less_ and _few(er)_ is not a silly rule made up by a prescriptivist. It's a natural part of the English language that's been around for millennia, but which is losing ground. _Feler_, the old comparative of _many_, has already completely lost out to _more_, and its antonym is on the wane as well. That doesn't make the old distinction silly or stupid, though, and if your aim is to write what readers will recognise as formal English, you should not simply ignore it.

Comment: In addition, language is not logic. The fact that _more_ works for both count and non-count nouns does not mean its antonym(s) work the same way. You might as well argue that since the comparative and superlative work for both count and non-count nouns, there's no need to distinguish in the positive, either; but that just doesn't make _*much houses_ any more English, nor does it make _little people_ and _few people_ mean the same thing.

Comment: @Janus BJ - Your assertions conveniently overlook the fact that every day, millions of native speakers of English break the 'rule' you are so strenuously championing; and what's more, they do so perfectly idiomatically and with no loss of clarity, comprehensibility or communicative power. I stand by every word: that so-called 'rule' is a heap of steaming crap. And don't put words in my mouth -- my objection to your position doesn't extend to defending _much houses_ or claiming that _little people_ and _few people_ mean the same thing. Keep your straw men tied to your leash, where they belong.

Comment: Your argument was that because _more_ works for both, so should _less/fewer_. That argument is no more valid than saying that because _more_ works for both, so should _much_. I am not disputing that _less_ is used with count nouns by native speakers, but just like with other linguistic variants that belong to certain registers only, that does not make it advisable to do so in _all_ registers. Formal writing is a register where I would strongly advise against using _less_ with count nouns, just as I would advise against using _ain’t_, even if both are perfectly fine in colloquial speech.