# "Must of " vs "must have"

Tags: idioms

I was browsing a completely unrelated [site](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1250160) and came across the following interesting discussion on the ever increasing proliferation of the phrase, "must of":

> ... You mean "must have", btw. Or "must've". Spelling it 'must of' is wrong.
>
> I suspect that "must of" is one of those phrases which is on the cusp of changing from "ever so wrong" into something that is perfectly acceptable.

I am interested in finding historical examples of a similar phrase moving to mainstream despite its initial non-aligment with conventional grammatical rules, and would be grateful if anyone could provide some concrete examples.

Comment: For some of them, very likely. For others, not so much. However, I think this question would fit better at crystalball.stackexchange.com. It is hard, if not impossible to predict how language will evolve, as it depends on its users — and in the case of English, they are many and diverse! I'm afraid that speculation about such future evolution is too broad for this site.

Comment: @oerkelens very funny. I am surprised that the evolution of language is considered off topic here, especially as it has been studied quite seriously by eminent names in the field.

Comment: It's not the evolution, its *future* evolution. If there were some laws making a particular phrase more likely to move "to mainstream", there would've been something to discuss.  
If you rephrased your question to "could you provide historical examples of a similar phrase moving to mainstream despite its initial non-alighment with grammar rules?", then there might've been something interesting to read in the answers.

Comment: @CopperKettle thanks for the constructive advice - will update accordingly :)

Comment: Can we vote on which we think will become accepted sooner, _must of_ or _prolly_?

Comment: Using *of* in place of *have* (especially in "should've") has likely crossed the threshold in British English already. I don't have it in front of me right now, but I believe the dialogue in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* uses *of* exclusively. (It's global-searched-and-replaced to *-'ve* for the American *Sorcerer's Stone*.)

Comment: @JohnY having read all of them (a guilty pleasure!) British English versions, I don't recall having seen "of" used in this context, and I am sure I would have remembered it, since I find this kind of deliberately unconventional grammar quite jarring! Unless it was used for character development of course. I will check later ...

Comment: @JohnY Rowling, I belive, read Classics at university,  so I find it hard to believe she used "of" naively

Comment: "some concrete examples" - is a concrete example as concrete examples came along well after "concrete" was used.

Comment: To judge from Google's ngram viewer, "must of" came up about 1900 and peaked about 1920-1960, a bit earlier in the US than in the UK. Maybe some author introduced this  in dialogues? But it seems to be declining. Of course this may be due to careful editing. Maybe the wrong spelling is more convenient when texting and will win for that reason.

Comment: @HansAdler Didn't its use proliferate for phonetic reasons and speakers' unfamiliarity with its written form?

Comment: @martin: Probably. My suspicion is that some authors used this spelling in dialogues (initially only) when uneducated people spoke, and that writing like this somehow became fashionable for a while. But I did not try to verify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more tricky example of wrong grammar becoming acceptable is usage of *who* vs. *whom*. *Whom* is the object case of *who*, but nowadays *who* is also fully acceptable for this purpose. As a consequence, some people are using *whom* in novel ways. They are already so numerous that it can't be called wrong any more.

In traditional grammar, *who(m)* when used as a relative pronoun takes its case from its function within the relative clause. (This is also how such things work in all other Germanic languages.)

- I gave it to him who needs it.
- The man whom we saw was in a hurry.

In the course of a general simplification trend of English grammar, *who* became acceptable instead of *whom*:

- I gave it to him who needs it.
- The man who we saw was in a hurry.

Then some people used *whom* as a marker of formal speech, even in situations where it doesn't fit. (Presumably because they didn't understand the rule any more.)

- I gave it to him whom needs it.
- The man whom we saw was in a hurry.

And nowadays there are even people who use *whom* as the form of the relative pronoun if and only if it refers to something that has the object case *in the main clause*:

- I gave it to him whom needs it.
- The man who we saw was in a hurry.

The issue prompted James Thurber to his hilarious 1929 satirical advice on proper distinction of "Who and Whom", and the confusion didn't get less since then.

Comment: You're right about the shift towards "who" in informal speech but it's still "wrong" in formal speech. The egregious misuses of "whom" you cite are not ever going to be generally accepted. The small subset of people who bother to use it will generally include more who understand it (at least on the "replace it with he or him" level) than don't.

Answer (score 3):

It used to be that people said *"I had rather do this"* (contracted to *"I'd rather"*).

Nowadays, this sounds incredibly old-fashioned. People say *"I would rather"* (contracted to *"I'd rather"*).

Of course, they're identical when they're contracted, which is probably responsible for the shift.

Comment: Might could be ([ngram backs you up on the general shift](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+had+rather%2C+I+would+rather&year_start=1500&year_end=2200&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20had%20rather%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20rather%3B%2Cc0)), but the fact that *would rather* is also *semantically* the more sensible of the two options probably plays into it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could look to to old meanings of words and check the time period it changed.

An example would be prove, like `"The exception that proves the rule."` as prove today means to demonstrate as true by evidence.

Today that sentence means "The exception provides evidence for the existence of the rule."

However, the old meaning of prove was to *test the rule*. Therefore, `"The exception that proves the rule."` used to mean "The exception that tests (the limits of) the rule."

The meaning shifted some time during/after the renaissance, I presume, as the old meaning of prove is categorized as Middle English.

I figure you're trying to figure what other words might have meanings that change, but that is hard to tell. Spellings can change based on understanding of colloquial English, but there are hundreds of different dialects, so what sounds like how something can be spelled in one dialect can be totally different in another.

Looking to the future, we now basically have an almost universally accepted dictionary of the English language all online, so any changing to the meanings of words will come about much more slowly and likely be debated and disputed for a long time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. "Answers" should attempt to answer the question (which was about *must of*), not engage in further discussion. This is different than forums. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: You seem to have misread the question. Kindly try again. Zavtra was completely on topic.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more notorious expressions (the OP asked for a phrase) which was considered absolutely incorrect in its infancy, but has today become so widespread that many speakers are unaware that it is, semantically speaking, contradictory  is

**could care less**

Wiktionary offers a descriptivist's approach

> **[could care less](http://could%20care%20less)**
>   (idiomatic, US) Lacking interest; having apathy towards.
>   Clipping of *couldn't care less*, which is literally accurate (having no ability to care less).
>
> **Usage notes**: This expression is a malapropism, since the literal meaning of this version is the opposite of the intended meaning.

Another infamous example is [**fewer** vs. **less**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)

1. Is it ‘less items’ or ‘fewer items’?
2. Is “There were less people than I thought” unacceptable compared to “There were fewer people than I thought”?

There will be staunch defenders on both sides of the tussle. Neither are wrong. Or maybe I should I have said, neither **is** wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Another example is **to beg the question**. It was properly a philosophical term of art that meant "to take more than one should from the question", to assume the truth of some part of the issue under discussion without proof or explanation. That's still the only definition offered by [the proper *OED* entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/17072#eid24510897) but *Oxford Dictionaries Online* now gives the more sensible modern misunderstanding—"to invite an obvious follow-up question"—[as its first result](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beg-the-question).

It's completely replaced the original meaning of the fairly common phrase, except among [sumpsimus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sumpsimus) philosophers who believe technically correct is the best kind.

There are also several examples that continue to irk across English's dialect lines. Brits inexplicably speak of **gents** and **ladies** without a possessive marker in sight, while Americans insist that their gas stations have **bathrooms**. (Brits generally used to and some continue to use it the same way but now more often take it as a point of local pride to resist the usage.) Things can also go the other way: [several features of Appalachian English](http://www.pbs.org/speak/seatosea/americanvarieties/smokies/) are considered to represent the area's lack of education when they actually preserve aspects of the pronunciation, grammar, and diction brought over with the area's settlement. **Ax** for ask goes back to Old English and so does the idea of adding prefixes like **a-** to the beginning of verbs like *a-fixin' to go get sth*.