# Why is the phrase "less than 15 people" incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

Why is the phrase *less than 15 people* incorrect? I just heard a radio personality flipping out over this usage.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please see *["Less" vs. "fewer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)*. I also encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Also, please try to add some context to your questions - we cannot tell you why that statement is incorrect without knowing what it is in reference to.