# Why is the word "fewer" seemingly doomed?

Tags: word-usage

More and more I see the word "fewer" less and less.  It's being replaced by "less" and seemingly falling into disuse.  What is the reason for this?  Is it as simple as the marketeers believing, "fewer calories" sounds "stuffier" than, "less calories," or is there some other reason?
(Please note I'm not asking for when to use each word.  I'm curious about a trend I've observed in the usage itself.)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Less" vs. "fewer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)

Comment: [Counting blindly, 'fewer' has always been less common than 'less', and contrary to your observation, 'fewer' has become more common over the past century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fewer%2Cless&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). But that's a very context free graph.

Comment: I would attribute it to marketing , yes, but simply because "less is more" and "more is less" sound better/make more sense than "fewer is more" and "more is fewer."

Comment: Because any time you say a word is "doomed" it looses "face" to the other words and slips into a cave to hide its shame.

Comment: Because "lesser" is preferred by people of a lesser grammar-god.

Comment: To me, the trend is similar to verb regularization.  There is a tailwind towards what's simpler, with fewer baroque rules.  Since the antonyms for "less and fewer" are "more and more" there's pressure to eliminate fewer.

Comment: Because people aren't learning this stuff in school, and feel that anything goes when it comes to expression.