# Discrete units of continuous quantity

Tags: grammar, countable-nouns, uncountable-nouns

Is it proper to speak of units of a continuous quantity as if they are discrete or continuous?

For example, I never know whether I should say that some food has "less calories" than another food (because the calorie is a unit of energy, which is continuous) or that it has "fewer calories" (since the calorie is a unit of measure and spoken of in plural).

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Less" vs. "fewer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)

Comment: Regardless of whether you think of it as a unit of energy or measure, a *calorie* is still a ***unit*** (that's to say, you can ***count*** them - they don't represent a "continuum", like, say, *volume* or *weight*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess I don't really understand the rule. You can have parts of calories

Comment: @FumbleFingers I also don't think this is a duplicate of that question because that question asks about what the difference is in general. I know that the difference is continuous vs. discrete but my question is about how the rule is applied in a particular case.

Comment: As the top answer on the linked question indicates, the relevant "rule" is a piece of pedantic poppycock that's always been either unknown to or ignored by the vast majority of native speakers. But in the case of, say, *calories*, you can tell they're always countable because we never say *How much calorie(s) does this cake contain?* - it's always *How **many** calories?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers My question includes whether saying _how many_ calories is correct.

Comment: If by that you mean you want to know whether *How much calories is in this cake?* is "valid" or not, I suggest that the question is either Too Basic, or belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand that _too much calories_ is not colloquial, but perhaps people are speaking incorrectly.  The responses that I'm getting are suggesting the answer to my question, but I don't see why the question itself should be considered invalid.

Comment: If *this* specific case deserves its own answer, where would we draw the line? You imply we should also accept separate questions asking about *How much ounces / inches / dollars does this weigh / measure / cost?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't trying to ask specifically about calories. That's an example. My question is asking about the general case of speaking of units of a continuous quantity as discrete or continuous.

Comment: We treat discrete approximations to continuous measures, and elided forms, as singular amounts: 3 years is a long time to wait / 50 miles is far enough away /  [A temperature of] 55 degrees is too hot / 636 is a lot of runs.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is simple, and you obviously know it: discrete quantities require the use of "fewer" and continuous quantities require the use of "less".

Calorie, as a unit, requires the use of "fewer".
Energy, as a continuum, requires the use of "less".

"Fewer calories means less energy."

In the same way, although it's a bit awkward, one should refer to units of volume with "fewer" and volume itself as "less".

"Fewer liters means less volume."

Comment: The true situation is far from simple. 'That's one less problem' has acquired idiomatic status. And few people would say 'Today's journey means we've fewer miles to do tomorrow.' The 'fewer/less' issue is only one aspect. We'd use '20 miles is a long way to walk', '10 minutes is not enough', '2 pints is ample' etc.

Comment: Idioms are irregular by nature. What rule in English would be complete without an exception?

And you're right that "We've fewer miles to do tomorrow" is rarer than "We have less distance to travel tomorrow." Sometimes a correct form is awkward, but using "less miles" or "fewer distance" would be incorrect in any case, so the rule stands.

Also, "long" describes "way," not "miles"; "not enough" is followed by an implied "time"; and "ample" is followed by an implied "volume". While these adjectives can't be applied to discrete units, discrete units can be in the same sentence.

Comment: A bald '[t]he rule is simple' is misleading.

Comment: Edwin meant "idiomatic" in the sense of it being ordinary and typical English, not "related to an idiom" in the way you seem to have understood it. These expressions are NOT irregular by nature. "Less than five litres" is another example. This answer is at best incomplete and very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In formal writing, say **fewer calories**, because that's the *correct* one.

In the grocery store you can use either one.  Suppose you and your slightly overweight pre-teen are in the grocery store reading nutrition facts together.  You might say, "I agree, this one's the better choice -- it has **less calories** and more fiber and protein."

However, you'll always need to say, "How many calories does such-and-so have?"