# Much and many: the opposite of less - fewer debate?

Tags: differences, word-usage

This morning, I corrected my little son on his use of *much*.

> I don't have much Star Wars guys.

He seems to use this word quite frequently in place of *many*, although he doesn't often use *many* in place of *much*.

As I reflected on the general rule - much for continuous and many for discrete - I thought about how it's the same rule that I use for less or fewer.

Now there is an interminable debate over the [distinction of less and fewer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/495/8360), which it seems boils down to [*less* is always fine](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/505/8360), and so I wonder if there is the same debate for their opposites (though I've never heard of it).

How often is *much* substituted for *many*? Is it often enough to be considered acceptable usage?

Comment: Using "much" there is very alarming but I've seen it done. I always assumed the offender was not a native speaker, but I guess that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: I never (to my knowledge) use 'much' with a count-usage or 'many' with a noncount-usage. 'There were many miles left to travel' but 'Twenty miles is a long way to walk'. // This contrasts with the idiomatic 'That's one less problem for us to have to solve' etc.

Comment: There's been [a steady decline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+fewer+than%2Fare+less+than&year_start=1870&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28are%20fewer%20than%20/%20are%20less%20than%29%3B%2Cc0) over the past century and more for the relative frequency of *are **fewer** than* as compared to *are **less** than*. I think it's unlikely this reflects a significant change in average ***context*** - it seems pretty obvious to me that *less* people like using *fewer* in contexts where their parents did.

Comment: Fewer is for things you count, and less is for things you don’t count. Many is for things you count and much is for things you don't count.

Comment: This question has already been answered here [Difference between "much, many, a lot of and lots of"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31719)

Comment: It costs less than 10 dollars vs. It costs fewer than 10 dollars. Children seem to develop concept about quantity first and they always want "much"  everything.

Comment: The _much/many_ distinction seems to be a real one in (most people's) English, and I don't see a decline in it. The insistence on _fewer_ for count nouns seems to go back to 1770, and I'm not convinced that it is part of anybody's English before the pedagogues get at them.

Comment: *much* is for singular, *many* for plural, and they are not interchangeable. Ever except for maybe 1 example. You can use *a lot* for both singular and plural, though.

Comment: @David I didn't ask what they mean. In fact, I defined it in my question. I'm asking about usage.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox The link answers the usage question. You must have missed the answer that says ""Much" is used for uncountable nouns, "Many" is used for countable nouns, "

Answer (score 6):

The [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/many-much/) hints at this 'ungrammatical' usage. It appears it may appeal to young people, probably because of usage,   for instance, in rap/hip hop lyrics:

***Much vs many:***

> - ***There is little controversy around the many-much distinction, and it is borne out with only rare exceptions.***  You might occasionally encounter a much dollars or a much people, but few English speakers use such constructions out of habit.
> - ***The distinction can be tricky in a few rare instances.***
>
>   - For example, while many thanks is more common than much thanks, the latter appears fairly often because we can think of this thanks as a mass noun (synonymous with gratitude) that takes a plural form by convention. Of course we can also think of thanks as an abbreviation of the plural noun thank-yous, in which case many is appropriate.
>   - And then there are singular mass nouns that sound plural. Kudos, for one, is a mass noun that happens to end in s, so the phrase many kudos is more common (on the web) than much kudos even though the latter is more logical.

Comment: Bottom line: you can't interchange them and stay grammatically correct. Ever. Correct me if I'm wrong! (But I'm pretty sure I'm right)

Answer (score 2):

"much/little" + singular, "many/few" + plural. I don't see any cause for debate.
I have never heard something like "much for continuous, many + discrete". Where did you find this queer rule?

Comment: Continuous = noncount, discrete = count, if that helps. Different words, same concept. Comes from a math background. This doesn't answer my question though.

Comment: much/little: non-countable (is infinite and cannot be enumerated); many/few: countable (finite or infinite, but can be enumerated)