# Should "less" or "fewer" be used in these examples?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, word-usage, ambiguity

For example:

> I need a tire with less ply.

or

> I need a tire with fewer ply.

Is "less" correct because ply is a singular noun? Or should it be "fewer" because it refers to a specific count of plied material? Or should "fewer plies" be used to reduce ambiguity?

A quick Google search seems to show that "fewer ply" is much more common. However, it could lead to confusion in the example below:

> Continuing trend toward fewer ply tires is expected." -[Technological trends in major American industries](https://books.google.com/books?id=5Pb99UZL5CwC&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=fewer+ply&source=bl&ots=KJEepbijM0&sig=nFj11XmtFx97S2z9EE8Vjifa5R8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkneP797TOAhVMOiYKHQeQCc4Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=fewer%20ply&f=false)

It might seem that it refers to the number of tires as opposed to the having fewer plies, which seems to be the intention.

Another example could be toilet paper:

> I normally use 3 ply, but now I am searching for a brand with (less/fewer) ply.

Comment: The 'fewer for discrete, less for continuous' distinction doesn't hold rigorously. 'That's one less problem' is the idiomatic choice. Here, though 'ply' is a count concept, and especially because 'ply' rather than 'plies' is used, I'd go with 'less'. This seems in line with usages found in a Google search for "fewer ply" and "less ply".

Comment: The article you cite includes this sentence: "Experts claim that tires with fewer, stronger plies build up less heat with no less strength than tires with more plies." Writers use the singular form _ply_ when they are using the word as part of an adjective phrase modifying an explicit or implicit noun, as in "three ply tires" or "3 ply [toilet paper]." When _ply_ functions as a noun and the author means to refer to more than one ply, he or she normally uses the plural form _plies_. Hence, "I need a tire with fewer plies."

Answer (score 4):

Fewer is used when referring to countable quantities (in which case the noun is usually in plural), and less is used when referring to uncountable quantities (in which case the noun is usually in singular). So I would say *fewer cows*, but *less milk*.

If I understand correctly, a *ply* is a layer. So *plies* would be countable quantity, just like *layers*, and I would say *fewer plies* as you suggested yourself.

However, I can imagine that there could be situations where the word *ply* is sometimes used informally for something made of layers, for example as a shortening of *plywood*. In which case you **could** say ''less ply'' in this context, as it would actually be short for ''less plywood'', which is fine.

Comment: The 'fewer for discrete, less for continuous' distinction doesn't hold rigorously. 'That's one less problem' is the idiomatic choice.

Comment: What rule does hold rigorously, especially when you bring idiom and colloquial usage into it?! That's like saying that the rules for conjugating 'to be' are invalid because they don't hold in _The Wire_. The distinction is a pretty good guide in standard language.

Comment: I'm pointing out that '_Fewer_ is used when referring to countable quantities (in which case the noun is usually in plural), and _less_ is used when referring to uncountable quantities (in which case the noun is usually in singular).' violates the Gricean maxim of quantity. Even a 'nearly always' would have avoided this.

Comment: The fact that you have resorted to citing Grice is probably a violation of his own 'maxim of manner' (I had to look that one up).

Comment: You might like to look up a well-referenced discussion of the less / fewer debate in [this earlier article](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer). nohat's answer is particularly thorough. / As stated above, Google results seem to indicate that  'less ply' is the more common of OP's suggested variants (in searches for "less ply" + "tyre", etc)

Comment: The better rule is to say that *fewer* can only be used with countable nouns, while *less* can be used with both.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with *neither* in this case. The ply rating is a scale, and you should instead say "I need a tire with *lower* ply".

Comment: This is a good point. I guess that you'd also use this for toilet paper i.e. 'my bottom is sore because I used a lower ply toilet paper' rather than 'my bottom is sore because I used toilet paper with fewer plies'!

Answer (score 2):

> Both "fewer" and "less" imply a comparison with something in larger amount or number.  Although "less" is widely used in place of "fewer", particularly in informal writing and speech, the distinction between them seems useful.  "Fewer" applies to number. (Fewer horses are seen on the street these days).  "Less" can be used in several ways: less material in the dress, less coverage, less than a dollar.  (The less money we have, the fewer purchases we can make.)  —Harry Shaw [Errors in English and Ways to Correct Them]

"Less" would better suit your original sentence, IMV.

---

*Another example could be toilet paper: "I normally use 3 ply, but now I am searching for a brand with (less/fewer) ply."*

In that sentence, the ply is countable, so I would use "fewer".