# Should “fewer” or “less” be used when mass and countable nouns are combined in “and” clause?

Tags: grammar

Obviously, it is correct to say

> *More* apples and flour was purchased.

But how do I express the opposite statement?

> *Less* apples and flour was purchased.

or

> *Fewer* apples and flour were purchased.

or, perhaps, it's incorrect to mix them and it is only correct to say:

> *Fewer* apples and *less* flour was purchased.

?

Comment: Shouldn't the verb be plural? As in ..... apples and flour *were* purchased.

Comment: The following "I bought less apples and flour than I needed" Is  acceptable in an informal context.

Comment: Few people would say 'That's one fewer problem.' The less / fewer situation isn't as black-and-white as some would claim it to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should "less" or "fewer" be used in these examples?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342005/should-less-or-fewer-be-used-in-these-examples). Actually, it seems that there are multiple dups.

Comment: Not crazy about the 'was purchased' part.

Comment: @Drew This isn't a duplicate, because it focuses on the question whether the word “ply” is countable or not. No “and” there. I am still unclear if in such mixed case both “less” and “fewer” would apply, only one would apply, or neither.

Comment: I think the only proper solution is the last one. Anything else sounds wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

'Fewer apples and less flour' is the way I would use and prefer to read or hear this.

Comment: Trust Izabella. Apples and flour can be combined only as, for instance, 'stuff' or 'food' or 'comestibles'.

If you're talking about the combination, then 'less tuff' or 'less food' or 'fewer comestibles.

If you're talking about the individual items then 'fewer apples and less flour'