# Should I use "less" or "fewer" here?

Tags: word-choice

> When the rancher spends that 8 hours producing potatoes, she spends 8 hours **less** producing meat...

Is this usage of **less** correct, or should **fewer** be used instead?

Comment: Generally speaking, *fewer* is reserved for things that come in distinct countable units.  Whether "hours" come in distinct units or are considered to be on a continuum is a matter of context.

Comment: No one thinks "8 fewer hours" is the only right sounding fix?

Answer (score 1):

See: ["Less" vs. "fewer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)

> The relation between less and fewer is fairly complex. In non-count singulars only *less* is possible: *Kim has less/fewer money than Pat*. In plural NPs we have:
>   [17]
>   *i. She left less than ten minutes ago.*
>   [...]
>
> Both [i] and [ii] have than + numeral. In [i] ten minutes expresses an amount of time rather than a number of individuated units, and in such cases fewer is virtually impossible—just as few would be in a comparison of equality: She left as little/*few as ten minutes ago. Similarly with We paid less than thirty dollars for it; She’s less than forty years old; We were going at less than ten miles an hour.

"Less than ten minutes" implies "eight hours less" is the more correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

According to Strunk and White (Mcmillan, 1979, page 51):

> ***Less***. Should not be confused with *fewer*.
>
> Left-hand column: He had less men than in the previous campaign.
>   [incorrect]
>
> Right-hand column: He had fewer men than in the previous campaign.
>   [correct]
>
> Less refers to quantity, fewer to number. "His troubles are less than
>   mine" means "His troubles are not so great as mine." "His troubles are
>   fewer than mine, means "His troubles are not so numerous as mine."

The OP's question concerns quantity not number (compare *quantity of time* to *number of time)*, so the example should read:

> When the rancher spends that 8 hours producing potatoes, she spends 8
>   hours **less** (not **fewer**) producing meat...

Comment: *When the rancher spends that 7.999 hours producing potatoes, she spends 7.999 hours ???? producing meat...*  Should it be *less* or *fewer*?

Comment: @HotLicks I could convert hours to seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds, femtoseconds, etc, but I have to admit you've got me there. :-) I was so quick on the draw, I not only missed the target, I shot myself in the foot. I've revised my answer. You framed your comment perfectly.