# Can I say "I have two pens less", and "I have two dollars less"?

Tags: comparatives, postpositive

There were 50 students in the class. The teacher gave out 50 pens to the students (the students got a total of 50 pens).

The teacher gave 50 pens to every student (every student got fifty pens each).
Everyone got 50 pens, but I got 48 pens.

So, can I say "**I have two pens less**"

Comment: There needs to be a reference to what this is two pens less than. "I have two pens less than everyone else," or "I have two pens less than the 50 everyone else has received." It _could_ be used if there is prior context: "Did you all receive exactly 50 pens? I have two pens less." // "I am two pens short" could be used as a stand-alone sentence.

Comment: Strictly speaking, shouldn't it be 'fewer', as pens are count nouns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Less" vs. "fewer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)

Comment: Did the teacher give 50 pens to every student, or a total of 50 pens to the 50 students (one pen to each student)? Your current wording contradicts itself.

Comment: All I can think now is "What the *** do you need fifty pens for?"

Comment: @MrLister she meant 'pence' :-)

Comment: @PabloDescamisado bingo! I too was puzzled by the title, but the context was a class, a teacher, students, and so pens seem to fit in well.  Why would a teacher give money (it's **pence** and **pounds** in the UK, and in the US it's **cents** and **dollars**) to students though? :P P.S You should have fixed the spelling, the grammar problem would have been easier to identify.

Answer (score 1):

A way to state your complaint is "I received 2 pens too few", or "I am 2 pens short".
Don't use "less" here, since the quantity is countable.  "Less" would be used for an non-quantifiable amount, for example, "I got less water than everyone else".

Answer (score 1):

Everyone got 50 pens but I got 48 pens. I got 2 fewer pens.