# Why are numbers exempt from the less vs. fewer rule?

Tags: grammar

The way I tend to apply the less vs. fewer rule is:

- If I can count it, it's **fewer** - *(Drink **fewer** glasses of water.)*
- If I can't count it, it's **less** - *(Drink **less** water.)*

But when it comes to numbers and time, I usually see **less** where either less or fewer seem to apply, for example:

- Less than 24 hours ago
- Fewer than 24 hours ago
- 10 items or less
- 10 items or fewer

I can count *hours* and *items*, and I can count ***to*** 24 and 10, but I can't count ***a*** 24 or 10.

Even though I see **less** applied, which is actually correct?

Comment: *10 items or less* is technically ungrammatical. It should be *10 items or fewer*. This is a hot topic for grammarians who don't like grocery store advertising. But despite it being strictly wrong, it's still become idiomatic. (And increasingly *correct through usage*.) As for the time, it depends on how you're using it. If you're counting actual hours, then (strictly speaking) it should be *fewer*. (*Fewer than 24 hours remain.*)  But, again, idiomatic usage has made both common.

Comment: Because you are confusing the attributes of the thing being measured with the notation of the measurement system. Time is semantically a continuum, like a sandy beach. Our habit of dividing it into numerable units doesn't change that. Also note that non-countable nouns, mass nouns, and continua aren't the same thing. Your taxonomy is a bit deficient.

Comment: @PhilSweet But my program uses less than 8KB of RAM, and they are definitely things I can count. Even though 1KB is easily broken down, and even bytes are easily broken down, you get to 1 bit and stop. We don't say our programs use fewer than 8KB of RAM.

Comment: @EdGrimm "fewer than 8 kilobytes of RAM" still sounds correct to me. And what are you using, a ZX Spectrum? XD

Comment: More relevant might be what program?  The only one I can think of that I've used lately that takes less than 8K of RAM is a stripped down version of /bin/true.  ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Less" vs. "fewer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer)

Comment: This is two questions disguised as one. (1) The **treating** of measures as continuous rather than discrete (even in those cases where etic counting, eg of pennies, is possible) (It cost less than $50 / It is less than 5 miles off / It happened less than 10 minutes ago ...). (2) The '10 items or less' / 'That's one less problem'  type of construction where 'fewer' would seem demanded, but isn't idiomatic. nohat addresses both.

Answer (score 2):

When a phrase beginning with a number denotes an uninterrupted sequence, eg. ten minutes, ten miles, ten kilos, it is the sequence as a whole that is being modified. Hence, "less than ten minutes" means "in a time shorter than a ten-minute duration."

Where the minutes are not contiguous, however, and we are actually counting them, then "fewer" can be used, as in "exercise breaks last up to a minute; in one hour, take fewer than ten minutes." If the time is one uninterrupted unit, we would say "take less than ten minutes."